# jQuery click event doesn't work if I refresh site when window width is bigger than 800px

Tags: javascript, jquery

So... in jQuery I have condition that says `if ($(window).width() < 800) {}` and inside of it I have this:

```
$(document).on ('click', '.menu', function () {
  $('.menuLinks').css({
    'animation-name' : 'menuLinks',
    'animation-duration' : '.3s',
    'animation-fill-mode' : 'forwards'
  });
});
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<header id="header">
    <a href="" class="logo">EXAMPLE</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="menuLinks">
      <a>example</a>
      <a>example</a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

And all of this I have in ready function. And my problem is when I refresh page and window width is smaller than 800px and click `.menu` it works, `.menuLinks` gets that CSS and everything works fine, but when I refresh it with window width bigger than 800px and than resize the window under 800px it doesn't work. If I want it to work, I have to refresh it with window width smaller than 800px.
Yes, I can put it in resize function, but when I refresh the page I have to resize window little bit to get it to work. I hope you will help me. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the click event handler outside of the if statement then wrap the inside of the handler with the if statement so it will look like

```
$(document).on ('click', '.menu', function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 800) {
        $('.menuLinks').css({
            'animation-name' : 'menuLinks',
            'animation-duration' : '.3s',
            'animation-fill-mode' : 'forwards'
        });
    }
});
```

The reason why the if statement should be moved inside of the event handler is because it will only define the event handler if the window width is less than 800 when the page fires the ready event. If the event handler is defined always and you check the window width inside of it, it will work.

Comment: yep, it fixed my problem. Thank you very much :D Idk why, but I can accept your answer after 3 minutes, I'll do it, don't worry :D